# selenium how to verify character font?

Tags: selenium, character, fonts

the problem as the title.

Comment: for example: [Answer Your Question] was bold in the page. with selenium how to verify it was bold???

Comment: css locator?  who could help me?

Comment: no people can give me a good idea???

Answer (score 3):

You should get the value of "font-weight" CSS property. In IE the bold value is "700" while in Firefox it will be "bold".

You need to get the computed style (FF) or current style (IE) of the element.

So for IE you will need to execute the following (it is in Java):

```
String strBold = selenium.getEval("var el = this.browserbot.findElement(<locator>);bold = el.currentStyle.fontWeight;");
boolean bold = "700".equals(strBold);
```

For the Firefox:

```
String strBold = selenium.getEval("var el = this.browserbot.findElement(<locator>);bold = window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue('font-weight');");
boolean bold = "bold".equals(strBold);
```

Comment: And to get other font attributes use "font-family", "font-size", "font-style", "font-variant"

Comment: I have no idea either - I have not asked any questions yet :)
It's ok, leave as it is or vote up :)