# HTML parser which can determine font size for specific node

Tags: html, css, parsing, fonts, colors

can anybody advise html parser which can provide displaying information about specific node: like font, color, probably location on the screen.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need a CSS parser too.

Answer (score 1):

Will you need to parse the linked CSS files? If so, have a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). And here is a related example of getting font weight:

[selenium how to verify character font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234670/selenium-how-to-verify-character-font)

Actually it's about writing JavaScript code to get the CSS properties.